# Still getting laravel validation error on address field even after entering entering the address

Tags: php, laravel, frontend

I am learning laravel and I am still at beginner level. I have used `php artisan make:auth` through which I have created the authentication code.

I have tried to add extra **address** field while registration. But while entering the details it is still showing that the address field  is empty.

**I want suggestions on how to remove the error**

*Thank you for your support*

[error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNOXu.png)

**RegisterController.php**

I have added also the address field in RegisterController.php

```
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'address' => ['required', 'text', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:6', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'address' => $data['address'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'username' => $data['username'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
```

**register.blade.php**

I have added also the address field in register.blade.php

```
<div class="form-group row">
   <label for="address" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('address') }}</label>
   <div class="col-md-6">
   <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" address="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autofocus>
   @if ($errors->has('address'))
        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
            <strong>{{ $errors->first('address') }}</strong>
        </span>
   @endif
   </div>
</div>
```

User.php:

I have added also the address field in User.php

```
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email','username','address', 'password',
    ];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input field doesn't have the `name` attribute. It's required to have it forwarded in your post data.

It seems like you've named the `name` attribute `address` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As Repox said Changes your this line

```
 <input id="address" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" address="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autofocus>
```

To this

```
  <input id="address" name="address" type="text" class="form-control{{ $errors->has('address') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" address="address" value="{{ old('address') }}" required autofocus>
```